# AngularJS Directive for downloading excel file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following HTML code in my AngularJS- application:

```
<a href="/api/schedulerecordexcel/{{vm.reportInstitution.id}}/{{vm.reportUser.id}}/{{vm.reportYear}}/{{vm.reportMonth}}"><img src="./Excel.PNG" alt="excel" /></a>
```

and this works fine. I need this code very often, therefore I decided to make a directive but I have almost no experience in making directives. 
This is my first approach:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApplication.common')
    .directive('asExcelDownload', asExcelDownload);

function asExcelDownload() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    ////////////

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        // TODO
    }
}
})();
```

Can give me someone any hint if I am doing right and what to do in the link function (if this function is ok)?

Comment: Write a Service which does an http call to download your Excel. And call that from controller inside your directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
angular.module('myApplication.common').directive('asExcelDownload', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          vm: '='
        },
        template: '<a ng-href="/api/schedulerecordexcel/{{vm.reportInstitution.id}}/{{vm.reportUser.id}}/{{vm.reportYear}}/{{vm.reportMonth}}"><img src="./Excel.PNG" alt="excel" /></a>'
      };
   });
```

**Usage:**

```
<asExcelDownload vm="vm"></asExcelDownload>
```